# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" in C#

Tags: c#, oledb

I have a numeric "userID" in a string variable.  I am converting it to `int` to get "username" and "roles" from the database which has a "user_ID" field with an AutoNumber datatype.  The converted userID is assigned to the variable "value".  But I am getting "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" in the line:

```
OleDbDataReader roleReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Here is the full code

```
class HomeClass
{
    string userID;
    string role;
    string username;

    public HomeClass(string myUserID)
    {
        userID = myUserID;
    }

    public string checkRole()
    {
        int value;
        value = Int32.Parse(userID);
        string query = "SELECT role FROM userAccounts WHERE user_ID = '" + value + "'";
        ConnectDatabaseString myConnectionString = new ConnectDatabaseString();
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString.connect();
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader roleReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        roleReader.Read();
        role = roleReader["roles"].ToString();
        return role;
    }

    public string getUsernameToBeShown()
    {
        int value;
        value = Int32.Parse(userID);
        string query = "SELECT username FROM userAccounts WHERE user_ID = '" + value + "'";
        ConnectDatabaseString myConnectionString = new ConnectDatabaseString();
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString.connect();
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader usernameReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        usernameReader.Read();
        username = usernameReader["username"].ToString();
        return username;
    }
}
```

What is the root cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a string literal in your SQL query.  EG `'value'` `'` means the datatype is a string.  Remove this and you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: @AmvinCinco You tried removing both as well as the additional quotes?

Comment: yes sir... here is query now... string query = "SELECT role FROM userAccounts WHERE user_ID = " + value; i did the same for the query in the other method

Comment: @AmvinCinco Can you show your db table definition?  Also, you should load the reader into a `DataTable` with the `Load` method.

Comment: i got it already.. hehe.. just got errors from other classes.. removing the single quote helped.. thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL statement, you're comparing `user_ID` to a *string* literal (in quotes).

You want to compare it to a number.